# Aggregate query in multiple collections Mongodb (pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I want to apply the aggregate query in multiple collections.
I have the following collection, One field is common in each collection `partner`, I wanted to filter out from all collection where `partner`  contains `john`, here is my collections -

**company**

```
{
    'com_id': 121,
    'name': 'abc',
    'pin': 45009,
    'partner': ['john', 'mack', 'michel'],
    'type': 'company'
}
```

**ventures**

```
{
    'ven_id': 342,
    'type': 'real_estate',
    'partner': ['john', 'duke', 'michel']
}
```

**property**

```
{
    'prop_id': 213,
    'address': 'xyz',
    'partner': ['john', 'gore', 'tiger'],   
    'type': 'property'
}
```

and wanted expected result as-

```
[
{'type': 'company', 'id': 121, 'name': 'john'},
{'type': 'real_estate', 'id': 342, 'name': 'john'},
{'type': 'property', 'id': 213, 'name': 'john'}
]
```

here's what I have tried but it didn't work for me.

```
mydb.company.aggregate([
        {'$match': {'partner': {'$in': ['john']}}},
        {'$lookup': {'from': "ventures", 'localField': "partner", 'foreignField': "partner", 'as': "final_data"}},
        {'$lookup': {'from': "property", 'localField': "partner", 'foreignField': "partner", 'as': "final_data"}},
])
```

Comment: Use three queries instead of `$lookup`

Comment: @Ashh Can you please give example, I really have no idea

Comment: I am suggesting you "is to use three queries with three queries" with this condition `{'partner': {'$in': ['john']}` and then concat all the arrays to get the desired output.

Comment: I did that but that is taking too much time, So thought to do using aggregate.